# Clean tabs from free-text column in tab-delim file

Tags: macos, shell, csv

I've been sent a tab-delimited file where free-text notes include unescaped tabs. There a 19 columns in the data and the free text is column #13. Thus I need to find all rows with >18 tabs. for such rows I need to replace any tabs that are >12 from the beginning of the line and >6 from the end of the line.  i'd like to replace with them with the string '@@' ( x at symbol) as i'll put the tabs back further downstream.

File is 2405 rows including header row and some rows have blank 'cells' , i.e. tabs next to each other.I can't get to the doc source not does supplier know how to fix source. Text is UTF-* and contains accented characters and such (i.e. not basic ASCII text).

Any simple method top fix this I can use on a Mac running OS 10.8.5 (or if necessary 10.9.x)?

Might help later readers if answers indicate if the splits (here 12 / 6 of 19) are hard coded or input as variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following `awk` command:

```
awk -F '\t' -v expectedColCount=19  -v freeFormColNdx=13 '
  NF > expectedColCount { 
      # Calculate the number of field-embedded tabs that need replacing.
    extraTabs = NF - expectedColCount
      # Print 1st column.
    printf "%s", $1
      # Print columns up to and including the first tab-separated token
      # from the offending column.
    for (i = 2; i <= freeFormColNdx; ++i) { printf "%s%s", FS, $i }
      # Print tokens in the offending column separated with "@@" instead of tabs.
    for (i = freeFormColNdx + 1; i <= freeFormColNdx + extraTabs; ++i) { 
      printf "@@%s", $i
    }
      # Print the remaining columns.
    for (i = freeFormColNdx + extraTabs + 1; i <= NF; ++i) { 
      printf "%s%s", FS, $i
    }
      # Print terminating newline.
    printf "\n"
      # Done processing this line; move to next.
    next
  }
  1  # Line has expected # of tabs or fewer (header line))? Print as is.
  ' file
```

Comment: Many thanks - worked a charm - especially as I realised the freeFormColNdx needed to be 12 not 13! Only newbie issue I had to figure out was output. My last line of the script became: `' source.txt > ouput.txt`

Comment: @mwra: Glad to hear it; my pleasure.